# How to deal with a note-making website when I need to store and redisplay information of user-selected vocabularies and phrases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, database

My plan is to set up a foreign-language-learning note-taking website using 
 python django framework.

The website mainly features these characteristics:

- user can type in paragraphs in two different languages and match them later on( I can solve this  by myself so you don't need to answer this)
- the website detects the events of user highlighting some words/sub-sentences( I can imagine how to solve this  by myself so you don't need to answer this)
- user can add comments on what they've highlighted; however I don't have a concrete plan on some best practice of **saving and re-displaying** what the users have done to their added notes/comments. To be exact, I am meaning that when a user later opens his/her saved notes, how do I design my **database schema** so that when he/she hovers on one vocabulary/phrase, the website automatically responds him/her the note which was saved before?(For example, do I need to memorize the position of each words?)

---

The answers I need could be in the format of codes or some detail concepts explanations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One resource friendly approach can be to save the word number(s) against saved note(s).

Like for a paragraph say

> We love stackoverflow. A wonderful place for community to interact.

And suppose you want to save note "I should replace wonderful with some other word" for "wonderful place". Then you schema might look like.

[image]

That way you can fetch only notes for the current word count range getting displayed plus you can support multi-comment.

Only thing you have to manage is if somebody come and edit the text then how you want to handle it like when somebody deletes 1 word you want to retain the note or update the note with any new word in its place.